# How to use Drone with self-hosted git repository

Tags: drone.io

I have a self-hosted git repositories (not GitHub, not Gitlab, etc)

Is there a way to configure Drone to work with my repo ?

Comment: What are you using to self host your git repo?

Comment: @John - just a bare repo over ssh

Answer (score 0):

If you are hoping to have builds auto-triggered by push commands, Drone needs one of the following Git solutions to add webhooks to to watch for changes: https://docs.drone.io/installation/

If you just want to use a `.drone.yml` file and run it locally manually you can use the Drone CLI and this command: https://docs.drone.io/cli/drone-exec/

The CLI command will run just like you would build on a server, except it uses your local machine as both the server and the agent. Also all items such as secrets must be passed into the `drone exec` CLI command.